# Why empty element is equal to 'empty soul'

Tags: ruby, iterator

I've got following piece of ruby code

```rb
[].all? { | item | item == 'empty soul' }
=> true
```

I expect it to be `false`

Comment: This is from the docs: __The method returns true if the block never returns false or nil__.

Comment: The concept is called [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Comment: Note : It's not an empty element, it's an empty list. There's no element!

Comment: All the items that are in the collection satisfy the predicate. Or can you show me one that doesn't? ;-)

Comment: I will when you show me one that does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how math works.

```
∀x ∈ X: p(x)
```

is the same as

```
¬∃x ∈ X: ¬p(x)
```

---

Or in Ruby:

```
friends.all?(&:insane?)
```

is the same as:

```
!friends.any? { |friend| !friend.insane? }
```

---

Or in human:

> All of my friends are insane.

is the same as:

> I don't have a friend who isn't insane.

---

All of the above are still equivalent, even in the corner case when I don't have any friends.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have no items. None of your items return a falsey value (`false` or `nil`). If that's not you want you can try

```
items.any? && items.all? { | item | item == 'empty soul' }
```

Comment: In fairness you could say no items satisfy the condition, which is the way I'd naturally expect the method to behave

Comment: @Mark: Actually, every single item that is in the collection *does* satisfy the condition.